# Can't Access Previous Purchases under Family Sharing

Tags: itunes, icloud, ios-appstore, mac-appstore, family-sharing

I recently switched to Family Sharing. Previously, we all had our separate iCloud accounts for contact syncing, calendaring, reminders, etc. and shared a single account for out store purchases.

Now that we've family sharing setup, besides still using separate iCloud accounts for the above purposes, everyone started using their own iCloud accounts for their store purchases as well.

When I go to `Settings > Apple ID > Family Sharing > Share Purchases`, I see that the old account we used to share for our store purchases is listed as to be shared among family members but when I recently tried to download a past purchase with that account, I repurchased it(I was logged in to the store with my own iCloud account).

What should I do if I want to be able to access my previous purchases?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally got around this pesky problem. And actually it was pretty straightforward!

All I had to do was add that old shared account as a separate family member. Hence now everybody only uses their respective iCloud ID for their personal stuff and purchases while sharing their old/new purchases.

This might not be a solution for you since family sharing only accepts 6 family members at the most as of now although there isn't any other solution currently.